# automation of the phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-chrome, phpmyadmin

[image]

I would like the date to change as many days as is given in the "interval" when I change vacation from 0 to 1

Here I paste my sweat;)

```
update employee_table
set date_nastne = date_nastne + "interval"
where added = 1
```

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a web application that you can use to manage and query a MySQL database. MySQL is the database.

Comment: okay, sorry for my mistake. can you know how to resolve my problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Triggers only run when something is changes, you can't trigger when something is selected.

Comment: yes, in another tab it will change from 0 to 1 and then I would like the date to change as well

Comment: Please edit the question, and show sample data and results. Show the original table contents, the change you're going to make from a tab, and the desired change that the trigger should make to the table.

Comment: okay one minute

Comment: everything changed, I hope now everything will be known

Comment: Where are you changing `vacation` from 0 ro 1? The only change you show is setting `interval`.

Comment: yes, but the vacation can also change here from 0 to 1 and I want the date to change then by as many days as is given in the interval

Comment: I asked you to show it in the example. Please post plain text, not screenshots.

Comment: I mean, if I change any record from 0 to 1 (say vacation), the date will also change for as many days as is given in the interval. I don't know how else can I explain it to you ...

Answer (score 2):

Use an `IF` statement in the trigger that checks if you're changing `vacation` from `0` to `1`. If so, add the interval to the `date_nastne` column in the `employee_table`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON przykladowa
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.vacation = 1 AND OLD.vacation = 0
THEN
    UPDATE employee_table
    set date_nastne = date_nastne + INTERVAL NEW.interval DAY
    where added = 1;
END IF;
```